# how to Print data in each 10 second in android if Internet connection is on

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    CheckinternetConnection internet;
    TextView textview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        internet = new CheckinternetConnection();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_IDS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(internet, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(internet);
    }

    class CheckinternetConnection extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
                textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                new print().execute();

            } else {
                textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textview.setText("It Seems Internet Connection is off");
            }
        }
    }

    class print extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "heloo", 10000).show();
        }
    }

}
```

This is my code i am track internet is On or off using Local broad cast but i want print data in each 10 second using asynk task or Handler  class if Internet is On please tell me how to schedule time in asynk task or we should use handle class please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

You get this by changing your flow like below,

When you get the reciver you have to execute your AsyncTask and in that AsyncTask you have write code for check interent connection in doInBackground method and then when you get result you can toast it in onPostExecute method.

below is the code of async task,

```
public class InternetCheckActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

Context mcontext = null;    
boolean NetworkRes;
int callId;
String connRes = null;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;



public InternetCheckActivity(Context context, int callId) {
    this.mcontext = context;        
    this.callId = callId;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    if (isConnectedToInternet()) {
        connRes = "Sucess";     
    } else {
        connRes = "NetWork Error";          
    }   
    return connRes;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // write your code  
}

public boolean isConnectedToInternet() {
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mcontext);
    String url1 = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
    if (!networkconnection(url1,"Internet")) {
            return true;            
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean networkconnection(String strurl,String type) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strurl);
        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlc.setConnectTimeout(4000);
        Log.i("networkconnection", "Started connection to " + type + "url : "+ strurl);
        urlc.connect();
        System.out.println(type + " Response Code: " + urlc.getResponseCode() + " | Response Message: " + urlc.getResponseMessage());

        if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            Log.d("networkconnection", type + " Success !");
            return true;
        } else if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 404) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        Log.d("networkconnection", "MalformedURLException " + e1.toString());
        return false;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("networkconnection", "IOException " + e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: U mean i should write code in asynk task for check internet connection and that aasynk task will excute when in Oncreate Onressume ?

Comment: yes you have to do just like that. you will get the result same like you want by doing this.

Comment: how to execute this task and where we have to execute which method i mean and what par-meter we have to pass in that asynk task ?

Comment: i have post the entire code for this in new answer, you can get all the things for which you have asked in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Android AlarmManager. it will help you schedule a task on repeated mode.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/eA9siMWjLCmRhAbAJ5AnHW   am Using this code but unable to do please tell me where am doing wrong am using alarm manger

Answer (score 0):

Check below code, you will get everything by this,

**rechabilityActivity.this**

```
public class rechabilityActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionListener{

int tempint = 100;
Button btnNext;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

//When you call this on oncreate
new InternetCheckActivity(rechabilityActivity.this, tempint).execute();

//When you call this on button click 
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
new      internetCheckActivity(rechabilityActivity.this,R.id.btnNext).execute(); 
 }
 });
}
@Override
public void onconnectionChecked(String resuString, int callId) {
if (resuString.equals("Sucess")) {
// network rechable
switch (callId) {
case R.id.btnNext:
// perform action
break;
case tempint:
// perform action
default:
break;
}
} else if (resuString.equals("NetWork Error")) {
// network error 
} 
}
}
```

**ConnectionListener.java**

```
public interface ConnectionListener {
abstract void onconnectionChecked(String resuString,int callId);
}
```

**InternetCheckActivity.java**

```
package com.example.testapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

 public class InternetCheckActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

Context mcontext = null;
ConnectionListener connListener;
boolean NetworkRes;
int callId;
String connRes = null;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

public InternetCheckActivity(Context context, int callId) {
    this.mcontext = context;
    this.callId = callId;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    if (isConnectedToInternet()) {
        connRes = "Sucess";
    } else {
        connRes = "NetWork Error";
    }
    return connRes;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    connListener.onconnectionChecked(result, callId);
}

public boolean isConnectedToInternet() {
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mcontext);
    String url1 = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
    if (!networkconnection(url1, "Internet")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean networkconnection(String strurl, String type) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strurl);
        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlc.setConnectTimeout(4000);
        Log.i("networkconnection", "Started connection to " + type
                + "url : " + strurl);
        urlc.connect();
        System.out.println(type + " Response Code: "
                + urlc.getResponseCode() + " | Response Message: "
                + urlc.getResponseMessage());
        if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            Log.d("networkconnection", type + " Success !");
            return true;
        } else if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 404) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        Log.d("networkconnection", "MalformedURLException " + e1.toString());
        return false;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("networkconnection", "IOException " + e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i have tried same code But there is no toast or some thing is Fire when net is on